# Almost continuous and almost cocontinuous functors

Tags: category-theory, modules

I would like to consider Hom-like functors $H:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ defined between abelian categories or, more specifically, between module categories, in the following sense:

1. $H$ is left exact.
2. For each family $\{M_{\alpha}\}$ of objects of $\mathcal{A}$, with canonical projections $p_{\beta}:\prod M_{\alpha}\rightarrow M_{\beta}$, the induced homomorphism $\prod H(p_\alpha): H(\prod M_{\alpha})\rightarrow \prod H(M_{\beta}) $ is a monomorphism.

Dually, I would consider $\otimes$-like functors $T:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ that satisfy the following conditions:

1. $T$ is right exact.
2. For each family $\{M_{\alpha}\}$ of objects of $\mathcal{A}$, with canonical inclusions $i_{\beta}:M_{\beta}\rightarrow \bigoplus M_{\alpha}$, the induced homomorphism $\bigoplus T(i_{\alpha}):\bigoplus T(M_{\alpha})\rightarrow T(\bigoplus M_{\alpha})$ is an epimorphism.

There would also be the contravariant versions of these types of functors.

QUESTIONS:

Have these functors already been considered in general?

Do you know some specific examples, otherwise from the Hom and $\otimes$ functors?